# Find the inverse Laplace transform $f(t)=L^{-1}\left\{F(s)\right\}$ of the function $F(s)=\dfrac{7s−22}{s^2−6s+13}. $

Tags: laplace-transform

Find the inverse Laplace transform $f(t)=L^{-1}\left\{F(s)\right\}$ of the function $F(s)=\dfrac{7s−22}{s^2−6s+13}. $

$f(t)=L^{-1}\left\{\frac{7s-22}{s^2-6s+13}\right\}$.

I was trying to break $F(s)$ into simpler rational fractions by partial fraction, but I could not factor $s^2-6s+13$. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533478/inverse-laplace-transform-for-fs-9s-24-s2-6s13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: complete the square.....

Comment: After complete the square, I got $\dfrac{7s-22}{(s-3)^2+4}$, but I am still confused about how to proceed with partial fractions?

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much for the hint!